# How to use $each() inside jquery append to get object for conditions parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I got problem when i wanna put condition in my endpoint, i recently used jquery

This my code in view Laravel

```
<tbody id="tbody">
@foreach ($modul as $m)
<tr>
    <td><input id="id_menu" value="{{$m->id}}" type="hidden">{{$m->id}}</td>
    <td>
        {{$m->nama_menu}}
    </td>
    <td>{{$m->link}}</td>

    <td id="check" class="text-center">
        <input class="id_check" type="checkbox" 
        @foreach ($count as $c)
            {{$c->id == $m->id ? 'checked' : ''}} @endforeach
            >
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

This js script

```
<script>
function handleChange()
{
var level = $("#filter_level").val();
$('#tbody').html('');
$.ajax({
    type : 'GET',
    url : 'http://localhost:8000/user/rule/'+level,
    success : function(res) {
            $.each(res.modul, function(mkey, vm) {
            console.log(res.count)
            $('#tbody').append('<tr id="tr"><td>' + vm.id + '</td><td>' + vm.nama_menu + '</td><td>' + vm.link + '</td><td id="check"><input class="id_check" type="checkbox"></td></tr>');
                $.each(res.count, function(ckey, vc) {
                    if(vm.id == vc.id){
                    $('#tr').append('<td id=""><input id="id_check('+vm.id+')" type="checkbox" checked></td>');
                    }
                });
            });  
        }
    });
}
```

I have 2 array json that must be loop to get an object from that array
I want to implement this code from my Laravel to jquery

```
<input class="id_check" type="checkbox" @foreach ($count as $c) {{$c->id == $m->id ? 'checked' : ''}} @endforeach>
```

This view, when count_id and modul_id has same value, checkbox will checked

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1p7dx.png)

json array view

[image]

Comment: can you show  output of `res` as well ?

Comment: @Swati that json view in console log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give some  unique `id` to your `trs` currently all tr have same id in your code .Then , we need put `vm.id` value in some variable so that we can use it inside another loop.Also, maintain some count `0` or `1` depending on this checked or unchecked your checkboxes.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
//suppose this is your json data
var res = {
  "count": [{
    "id": 1
  }, {
    "id": 2
  }, {
    "id": 4
  }],
  "modul": [{
    "id": "1",
    "nama_menu": "ss",
    "link": "dd"
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "nama_menu": "sss",
    "link": "ddd"
  }, {
    "id": "3",
    "nama_menu": "ssss",
    "link": "dddd"
  },{
    "id": "4",
    "nama_menu": "smsss",
    "link": "dmddd"
  }]
}
handleChange();

function handleChange() {
  var level = $("#filter_level").val();
  $('#tbody').html('');
  /*$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:8000/user/rule/' + level,
    success: function(res) {*/
  $.each(res.modul, function(mkey, vm) {
    var id = vm.id //put id value in some variable to use in next loop
    var count = 0; //declare this
    $('#tbody').append('<tr id="' + vm.id + '"><td>' + vm.id + '</td><td>' + vm.nama_menu + '</td><td>' + vm.link + '</td></tr>');
    $.each(res.count, function(ckey, vc) {
      if (id == vc.id) {
        $('#' + id).append('<td id=""><input id="id_check(' + vm.id + ')" type="checkbox" checked></td>');
        count = 1; //set count  we found
        return false; //we found break loop
      }
    });
    //check if count is 0
    if (count == 0) {
      $('#' + id).append('<td><input class="id_check" type="checkbox"></td>'); //append unchecked checkbox
    }
  });
  /* }
  });*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody id="tbody">

    <tr>
      <td><input id="id_menu" value="12" type="hidden">12</td>
      <td>
        Abc
      </td>
      <td>oemthingss</td>

      <td id="check" class="text-center">
        <input class="id_check" type="checkbox" checked>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```